# vendor-bundle.js size in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I created my first Aurelia project with the cli tool. Now when I build (an almost empty) project with the prod environment I get a nicely minified output: (vendor-bundle.js, app-bundle.js).

The vendor-bundle.js is a healthy 400k minified, non-gzipped. When I look in my aurelia.json, I see a bluebird.core, require.js and a bunch of aurelia-* dependencies.

Is this is about the minimum framework-footprint I can get?

Kr,
Joris

Comment: You could try to delete individual dependencies that you won't use, but I think you'll find that most of them will be used for the most basic of Aurelia projects (routing, binding, framework, for instance).  But, then again, I'm not giving an authoritative response.  It would be good to hear from one of the Aurelia developers on this.

Comment: It's been 300k for me with webpack. But I have never built anything seriously with the cli though

Answer (score 0):

Like LStarky says, this is not authoritative. You would need to dig into the aurelia.json and start removing dependencies until you find the right combination for the functionality you are using. For a non-SPA type of aurelia app, I put some work into this and ended up removing several things like aurelia-router and aurelia-history. I got it down to 406K, but that is also including some other 3rd party libs loaded from `node_modules`. Thankfully the web server has gzip transfer enabled so it's not a huge deal to transfer the vendor bundle.

Comment: Still, it seems to love to pre-initialize everything on load, so it takes 150ms on a fast pc/browser, can't imagine the anguish IE users would feel on an older pc, ouch.